# Google Cloud Load Balancing: HTTP(S) Load Balancer Vs SSL/TCP Proxy Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, proxy, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

As per the Google Cloud documentation, HTTP(S) load balancer "is a proxy-based Layer 7 load balancer" whereas SSL/TCP proxy load balancers are "reverse proxy load balancers".

Could you please help me understand on what basis HTTP(S) load balancer is proxy-based and SSL/TCP proxy load balancers are reverse-proxy based?

Answer (score 1):

Proxy is a proxy. That means the connection from internet and the load balancer is terminated, and a new one is created between the load balancer and the backend service.

The passthrough is different, the connection is only routed but not terminated.

---

The difference between a HTTPS load balancer and a SSL/TCP load balancer, isn't the proxy mode, both use the same principle of connection terminaison. The difference comes from the OSI layer. 7 for the HTTPS, 4 for TCP/SSL, that's all.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. I'm clear about other things such as network layers, connection termination and passthrough etc... but was confused why it is documented as proxy based for one and reverse proxy based for the other.